# UINavigationBar appearance setBackgroundImage:nil doesn´t work on ios 5.1

Tags: ios

i set my UINavigationBar appearance with the following line:

```
UIImage *navigationBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeaderNavBar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I remove it with the following line:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This works on every ios, except on ios 5.1...Does somebody know why?!

Answer (score 0):

"When the contents of your view change, you do not redraw those changes directly. Instead, you invalidate the view using either the setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect: method." ([View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)).  Do you still have that issue after redrawing the view?

See also: [UIView Class Reference: setNeedsDisplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay)

Comment: My View don´t have a method called setNeedsDisplay?!

Comment: What about `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`? Should redraw the entire view but it would be good to see if it clears your UINavigationBar background.

Comment: `[UINavigationBar appearance] setNeedsDisplay]` works for me.

Comment: that gives me NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSMethodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [0, 1]'

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and then:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It is recommended [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/).